# How can I format a Data Item String

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

So I have a text field that I am calling in a Data Item from a DB list. I am trying to format this field so it only shows the last 3 digits of the passport number and then mask the first 6 with # signs. How can I do this inline or do I have to go to the code behind?

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="txtPassportNumber" 
    runat="server" 
    MaxLength="9" 
    text="<%# ((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber %>" 
    Enabled="<%# IsOutsideTenDayCutoff %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this yet:

```
text="<%# '######' & string.right(((TSAPassenger) Container.DataItem).Passport.DocumentNumber,3) %>"
```

But unless you need the number in your app, just call it that way from the database command instead.

Comment: So for some reason with the maxlength of 9 it gives me an error that there are too many characters in the literal

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Concat, where str is your DataItem string

```
    (str.Length==9) ? string.Concat(string.Empty.PadLeft(6, '#'), str.Substring(str.Length - 3)) : string.Empty;
```

You can change latter string.Empty to show some error or whatever you want for incorrect passport numbers.

Comment: sorry this didnt work either and I am not sure if its the code or not. It said the startindex couldnt be less than zero which i am not sure since if a passport number is empty some times if that would throw that error

Comment: You need to make sure that you have 9 characters before actually calling substring on it. see my edited answer

Comment: have u tried above solution? Please accept it as answer or else let us know any if you are still having issues...